# Initially not rendered styled-component doesn't loads its style

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When an styled-component isn't present in the initial render tree, it does not load its style. For example, I've a Card with some data that's fetched from the API, if the API takes more than 2 seconds (approximately) the styled isn't loaded.

```
const Card = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
`;

const ToDosPage = ({ createData, toDos, getData }) => {
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState({
    expirated: false,
    done: false,
    done_by: 2,
    task: 1,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    getData('toDos');
  }, [getData]);

  const renderToDos = () => toDos.map((toDo) => <Card>{toDo.title}</Card>);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{renderToDos()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToPops = (state) => ({ toDos: state.dataManager.toDos });

const mapDispatchToProps = { createData, getData };

export default connect(mapStateToPops, mapDispatchToProps)(ToDosPage);
```

I think that maybe the problem is in the index.html or the webpack:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--load all styles -->
    <title>
      my-app
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, {loader: 'postcss-loader', ident: 'postcss'}],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'development',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './src/store';
import ToDosPage from './src/pages/ToDosPage';
import TasksPage from './src/pages/TasksPage';
import Menu from './src/components/Menu';
import { colors } from './src/utils/constants';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Menu />
      <Route path='/todos' component={ToDosPage} />
      <Route path='/tasks' component={TasksPage} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess that fetching the data isn't causing `<ToDosPage>` to re-render with the newly fetched data. To get more confident, we'd need to see how `getData` is working, and how `todos` are passed as props to `<ToDosPage>`. Could you [edit] to include the parent component? You could also try rendering this without the API call by passing in static data to `toDos` The `index.html` and webpack config probably aren't relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually it's re-rendering, to be sure I added some console logs with the length of the toDos and I've '0' and '1' as console outputs because it's re-rendered whit the new component. I'm using redux to pass the toDos. I tried to pass static data using a 'setTimeOut' to delay the rendering of the static data and simulate that it's an API call, and I've the same problem.
Another thing that i tried is to add a forceUpdate after the data is fetched, but I had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of things I discover that it's a problem with some extensions in chrome. I disable all my extensions and it starts working properly.

edit: It could be any extensions, it doesn't have to  be related to react. For example in my case it were a Loom extension